# Migration update table with hash password

Tags: node.js, typescript, database-migration, typeorm

I need transform a string password in a hash in migration i use this code but transaction finish after select

````
    const users = await queryRunner.query('SELECT * FROM app_user;');
    users.map(async user => {
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
      await queryRunner.query(
        `UPDATE app_user SET passsword = '${user.password}' WHERE id = ${user.id}`,
      );
    });
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but I hope it would works

```
const users = await queryRunner.manager.createQueryBuilder().from('app_user', 'app_user').execute();
if (users.length > 0) {
  const passwords = await Promise.all(users.map(user => bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)));

  users.forEach((user, idx) => {
    queryRunner.manager
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update('app_user')
      .set({ password: passwords[idx]})
      .where('id = :id', { id: user.id })
      .execute();
  })
}
```